# Git hub as content management

Tags: github

I wish to put my project documentation and guides inside private github repo and give access to my team.
How can I restrict outside world to access by making best security measures on GitHub organisation account

Comment: you can pay for a private repo for like 9 bucks, https://github.com/pricing

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty cool to have **Github** as a content management, but **Github** but your information matters, there are things that cannot be open source: so you must pay for it.

Github offers different plans for private repositories, the cheapest is **$7** per Month as 2018.

[image: github plans]

See [github.com/pricing](https://github.com/pricing)

I currently have that plan and what I do to work as a team is create a private repository and for it into our team Organization, and then we have private repositories.